# Classical guitar intonation: B string madness

Tags: guitar, tuning

I'm a lapsed violist/pianist and have always also played guitar, first folk/rock and then for 20 yrs or so classical and Brasilian.  I have, for decades, noticed that it is almost impossible to tune the B string such that it is properly in tune both open and fretted, in different keys.  I often have to take pains to find the compromise between its intonation as open and its intonation as fretted, and that it changes according to the key of the piece.  This through many different instruments; however, some sets of strings seem a bit better than others in ability to sound in tune, particularly with major thirds.  My sense of pitch is acute in a relative sense, and the beats or heterodyning from the root note and harmonics drive me a bit nuts.  Why is this generally true of the B and not e.g. the G or high E?

Comment: In addition to the linked question on this site, there is a great deal of discussion of this issue in general. A Google search for [B string tuning problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=b+string+tuning+problems) will provide many resources.

Comment: Thank you both very much, am reading your references.

Comment: @Aaron - I thought one of the purposes of this particular site was to be a compendium of information for most things musical. It's important that we keep questions and their answers on site, rather than directing OPs to other sites. Maybe I'm missing the point here?

Comment: @Tim The question is a duplicate, so I pointed the OP to the relevant MP&T post. I supplemented that by pointing to additional places to find information. We routinely point users to external sources in addition the the answers posted here, so I'm not clear on what the problem is. (BTW, is there a way to move this to chat short of continuing to comment until the "would you like to move this to chat" message comes up?)

Comment: @Aaron - it's not a problem per se, hence only a comment.